# Trigonometric equation solving / 4th degree polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials, quadratics

Okay, so I was solving a free body diagram problem, no need to send it, but I found a very huge problem in doing so, in any way I tried solving , I either got to an equation $\sin(x-0.11)=4\sin(2x)$
or a 4th degree polynomial that my calculator wont possibly solve.
Any idea on any of the two and a general rule for the sine at least?

Comment: It doesn't look solvable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using angle subtraction formula for the left and double angle formula for the right:

$$\sin(x)\cos(0.11)-\sin(0.11)\cos(x)=8\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Comment: but this also wont help in giving x

Answer (score 1):

> *Okay, so I was solving a free body diagram problem*

Aha, say no more! A physics problem! :-$)$ This means that you'll probably settle for a high precision numerical approximation, since physicists, engineers, economists, and others who study applied mathematics<sup>1</sup> aren't exactly famous for their burning interest in closed form expressions, as those noble minds that pursue the higher spheres of pure mathematics<sup>2</sup> $($which under **no** circumstance whatsoever is to imply that other forms of mathematics are in **any** way, shape or manner impure $\ldots$ or so my *PR* people are telling me to write $\ldots$ since we're all so *PC*, tolerant, open-minded, and all-inclusive around here $\ldots)$

<sup>1</sup> Politically correct term for “impure mathematics”. Also politically incorrect, since it automatically implies that other branches are to some extent useless. See following footnote.

<sup>2</sup> Politically correct term for “useless mathematics”. Also politically incorrect, since it automatically implies that other branches are to some extent impure. See previous footnote.

$($It's getting harder and harder with each passing day to keep track of all those hurt feelings and offended sensibilities, not to mention possible grounds for future lawsuits $\ldots)$

---

Without further ado, the three main solutions for $|x|<\dfrac\pi2~($since this is the principal interval of the arcsine function$)$ are

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ [image]

Don't get me wrong, I've tried evaluating the general expression for $~\cos(a)~t-\sin(a)\sqrt{1-t^2}$ $=~8t\sqrt{1-t^2},~$ as well as using the fact that $\sin a\simeq a$ and $\cos a\simeq1$ or $1-\dfrac{a^2}2$ for small values of the argument, but they only yielded hideous expressions, which remained ugly even after applying further simplifications. Replacing *a* with $\dfrac19$ or $\dfrac{11}{100}$ did not work any wonders either; all it did was return the [quartic equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Special_cases_of_the_formula) of the [casus irreducibilis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis). So, to finally answer your question about finding “a general rule for the sine”, my reply would be to try a numerical approach $\ldots$ and please **trust** when I tell you that I am **not** the kind of person to dispense such advice *lightly* $\ldots$ The first two solutions are very close to $~\pm\dfrac{13}9,~$ and the third can be approximated by $0.01567$ : and that's about as *helpful* as I can get, I'm afraid $\ldots$

Comment: You make my day with your final recommendation !! Cheers.

Comment: So physically I couldnt get anywhere farther than this equation as a mathematical approach ... Ill just do a trail and error technique , thank you very much